# 標準偏差や平均値をグループ毎の上位に関して出したい

Tags: mysql

`select avg(point) from table where (genre毎のpoint上位100位まで) GROUP BY genre;`

みたいな事がしたいのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？
ポイント上位を入れたテーブルを作るくらいしか思いつかなかったので…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

最初は `IN` 演算子とサブクエリで処理しようとしたのですが、以下のエラーメッセージが表示されるので、

```
MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery
```

ユーザ定義変数(user-defined variable)とサブクエリを使ってみました。

```
SET @num := 0, @genre := '';
SELECT t.genre, avg(t.point) AS average
FROM (
  SELECT t2.genre, t2.point,
    @num := IF(@genre = t2.genre, @num + 1, 1) AS rownum,
    @genre := t2.genre
  FROM test2 AS t2
  ORDER BY t2.genre ASC, t2.point DESC
) AS t WHERE t.rownum <= 100 GROUP BY t.genre;
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました

Answer (score 1):

argusさんのユーザ変数を使った方法ですが、

OracleACEのAketiJyuuzouさんとyoku0825さんと
日本オラクルの木村さんによると 
MySQLのユーザ変数は評価順序が未定義だそうです。
http://qiita.com/AketiJyuuzou/items/cced9b70cc714b382d98

なので、結果が保証されません。

Answer (score -1):

コメントで勘違いしていると指摘してもらったので修正します。
これでMySQL特有の機能は不要だと思います。

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  name CHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
  point INT NOT NULL,
  genre CHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO items (name,point,genre) VALUES
  ("a1", 10,"A"),
  ("a2",100,"A"),
  ("b1",1000,"B"),
  ("c1",1,"C"),
  ("c2",3,"C");

SELECT genre, avg(point)
  FROM items I1
 WHERE (SELECT count(*)
         FROM items I2
        WHERE I1.point <= I2.point
          AND I1.genre = I2.genre) <= 100
 GROUP BY genre;
```

---

**以下は、問題の意味を勘違いしていたときのものです。

僕と同じ様な勘違いをする人もいるかもしれないので残しておきます。**

質問内容をよく分かってないかもしれませんが、
サブクエリとかMySQL特有の機能とか使わなくても
こんな感じじゃダメですか？

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  name char(30) PRIMARY KEY,
  point INT NOT NULL,
  genre char(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO items (name,point,genre) VALUES
  ("a1", 10,"A"),
  ("a2",100,"A"),
  ("b1",1000,"B"),
  ("c1",1,"C"),
  ("c2",3,"C");

SELECT avg(point)
  FROM items
 GROUP BY genre
 ORDER BY sum(point) DESC
 LIMIT 2;
```

INSERT をたくさん書くのた面倒なので limit 2 して、
3位だけ除去しました。
使う場合は、たくさん INSERT して limit 100 とかすればいいと思います。

あとは必用に応じてサロゲートキーとか付ければいいのかと思います。

Comment: そのクエリだと、グループ全体の平均値を、グループの合計ポイントが多い順に100グループになってしまいます。質問は、**各グループの上位100件**の平均値を求めるもので、グループ数に制限はありません。

Comment: なるほど! 了解しました。ちょっと説明しにくいですけど、だから row_number が必用なんですね。で、MySQL だと window関数がないから、変数使っているという事ですね。